# playsms - kannel -smsc Able to receive but not to send sms

Tags: sms-gateway, kannel

I use playsms and kannel, I can receive sms but i cannot send sms.

When I try to send a sms I got:
1. `0: Accepted for delivery in the browser`

2. `tail -f /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log`

   > ```
   >  sudo tail -f /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [3] INFO: smsbox: Got HTTP request from <127...*>
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [3] INFO: sendsms used by
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [3] INFO: sendsms sender:***> (127...) to:<2*******> msg:
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [3] DEBUG: Stored UUID f5a87ab8-bd95-413b-a9a6-eb37e9b454da
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [3] DEBUG: message length 14, sending 1 messages
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [3] DEBUG: Status: 202 Answer:
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [3] DEBUG: Delayed reply - wait for bearerbox
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [0] DEBUG: Got ACK (0) of f5a87ab8-bd95-413b-a9a6-eb37e9b454da
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [0] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x7f827c000a90.
   >     2015-07-20 15:20:12 [2711] [0] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for 127...*)'.
   >     2015-07-20 15:31:13 [2711] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for127...*)'.
   >     2015-07-20 15:31:13 [2711] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x7f827c000a90.
   > ```
3. In playsms the sms is pending and not sent

Have you any idea what is my problem?

Comment: check access log .... and make sure the smsc is properly defined

Comment: All thing is right ! just it was a problem with the sim card.

Comment: nice to know it is working now :)